# What is the real part of $(1-i)^{-i}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> What is the real part of $(1-i)^{-i}$?

I am stuck in this question and not able to solve. Please help me. I am only able to reach to this conclusion.

The real part of complex number $a+ib$ is denoted by Re(z)=a and it's imaginary part Im(z) is b. There is no information (in my book) for $a^b$ where b is complex

$$(1-i)^{-i}=(e^{\frac{-i\pi}{4}})^{-i} \times (\sqrt{2})^{-i}$$

Disclaimer : I am a high school student.

Comment: First, you need a definition for $a^b$ where $b$ is complex.  What definition do you use?  Please include it in the question.

Comment: Do you know $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cdot e^{i\tan^{-1}\frac{b}{a}}= a+ib$?

Comment: As suggested by GEdgar, $(1-i)^{-i}$ is not well-defined. You need to choose a principal value, since $\log(1-i)$ is only defined up to (an integer multiple of) $2\pi i$ and $e^{2\pi i\cdot (-i)}\neq 1$, which makes $(1-i)^{-i}$ defined only up to a multiplication by an integer power of $e^{2\pi}$.

Comment: No I don't know this. But I can prove this.$$|z| e^{i\theta}=a+ib$$

Comment: If you can prove the equation (slightly wrong because I considered only the principal domain), represent $1-i$ in this form and take the $-i^{\text{th}}$ root. exactly as indicated in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $1-i=e^z$ iff $z=\tfrac12\ln2-\frac{\pi i}{4}+2n\pi i$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$, [there are multiple definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_complex_bases) of $(1-i)^{-i}$, namely those of the form $\exp(-\pi/4+2n\pi-i\tfrac12\ln 2)$, with respective real parts $e^{-\pi/4+2n\pi}\cos(\tfrac12\ln 2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: I'm going to cheat and assume the "principal branch."

Rewrite $1 - i$ in polar form as $\sqrt{2}e^{-i\pi/4}$.

Then $(1 - i)^{-i} = (\sqrt{2}e^{-i\pi/4})^{-i} = \sqrt{2}^{-i}\left(e^{-i\pi/4}\right)^{-i}$.

This breaks down into two terms $\sqrt{2}^{-i}$ and $\left(e^{-i\pi/4}\right)^{-i}$.

For the first term rewrite $\sqrt{2}$ as $e^{\ln \sqrt{2}} = e^{(\ln 2)/2}$ so $\sqrt{2}^{-i} = \left(e^{(\ln 2)/2}\right)^{-i} = e^{-((\ln 2)/2)i}$ which is a number on the unit circle.

For the second term $\left(e^{-i\pi/4}\right)^{-i} = e^{(-i\pi/4)(-i)} = e^{-\pi/4} \approx 2.19$ which is a real number.

It is at this point that the cheat kicks in. We chose to write $1 - i$ with $\theta = -\pi/4$ but really we could have chosen $\theta = 7\pi/4$ or in general $\theta = 2 \pi n - (\pi/4)$. If we had done so we would have gotten $e^{i(2 \pi n - (\pi / 4))(-i)} = e^{2 \pi n - (\pi / 4)}$ for this term. The "principal branch" choice is that unique value of $\theta$ which satisfies $-\pi \lt \theta \leq \pi$, which in our case is $\theta = -\pi/4$.

Putting the two together we have $e^{-\pi/4} e^{-((\ln 2)/2)i}$. So in polar form we have $r = e^{-\pi/4}$ and $\theta = -(\ln 2)/2$.

The real part of this number is $r \cos \theta = e^{-\pi/4} \cos \left(-(\ln 2)/2\right) \approx 0.4288$.